# Is there any way to paste an image at the cursor in a Word 2016 document?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

Is there a way to simply paste an image in a Word document at the cursor?

Regardless of the Advance Word Options I have set (In Line with Text or Top and Bottom); images are pasted at some random location.  Sometimes images wind up at some random location on another page.

I used to be able to place images in table cells, but this does not seem to work any more.

Comment: Not as you mean it. You already are pasting at the cursor, but then the layout engine places it where it believes is appropriate.

Comment: Is there a way to override the layout engine and place the images at precise locations?

Comment: How come it doesn't seem to work anymore? you could post some screenshots or better yet upload a sample file. Because if you set the correct options in Word, everything should work.